# httpurlconnection openConnection returned false

Tags: android

I have web service written in c# and its working good
when I ask for this service from my android code it give me problem with the connection
my code look like this

```
 URL url;
try {
        url = new URL("http://192.168.1.35/Audio.ashx");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
```

when I debug it the connection parameters " connected = false "

Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the input stream from this you can then get the data as so:-

```
 URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://www.mysite.se/index.asp?data=99");

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();

        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

        int data = isw.read();
        while (data != -1) {
            char current = (char) data;
            data = isw.read();
            System.out.print(current);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Actually my link working good when I asked for it from mobile browser manually, but not from the code

Comment: Finally I found the answer, after openConnection(); we should write connection.connect(); and all will be good :)

Answer (score 0):

AndroidManifest.xml

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`